# jQuery target blank atr - where to include this in the script?

Tags: jquery, target

I have the following jquery script, which deals with a query site-visitors enter to search on external sites.

```
    $("#Sbutton"+i).click(function(){
        var my_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(8);
        //alert(my_id);
        SearchUrl = $('#Search'+my_id).val();
        SearchQuery = $('#String'+my_id).val();
        location = SearchUrl+SearchQuery;
```

Currently, the query is loaded in the same window as where the query is entered. I'd like to have this in a similar way as 'target:_blank'. It seems I have to use code something like ".attr("target","_blank")", but I can't seem to figure this out.

an anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put  $("#Sbutton"+i).attr('target', '_blank'); before your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do (or something like it):

```
<form class="searchForm" target="_blank">
   <input type="hidden" class="searchUrl" />
   <input type="text" class="searchQuery" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then your JS:

```
$(document).ready({
  $(".searchForm").bind("submit", function() {
    var SearchUrl = $(this).children(".searchUrl").val();
    var SearchQuery = $(this).children(".searchQuery").val();
    var location = SearchUrl + SearchQuery;
    $(this).attr("action",location);
    $(this).submit();
  });
});
```

The basic idea is, you create a handler on the parent form element, which then finds the appropriate data from within it and creates the location string.  The event handler then changes the action of the form to the new location string, and submits the form.

Comment: it's actually an <input> field, with a button.

Comment: Do you not have any <form> element wrapping it? If you don't, you really should.

Comment: While I admit I haven't tried this before, it doesn't seem to help - still the target is the same window. Could there be an overriding element somewhere?

Comment: It's possible it isn't triggering a submit event, depending on the specifics of how you have it set up.

Comment: Heh, I guess I'm not that good 'a coder. Would including <form target="_blank"> ... </form> be enough? (since the action is in the jquery script, right?)

Comment: I've written an updated response that tries to emulate the behavior of your form, but in a simpler way.  If you use <form> elements with <input type="submit"> as buttons, then you can leverage the powers of HTML without having to try to replicate its built-in behavior with javascript hackery.  I don't have your code, so of course YMMV, but the general principle is to keep it simple and use HTML where it's strongest, and use jQuery to support it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - to no avail yet, though. While I'm sure the code you provided works well, I can't seem to figure out how to solve it - problem is, the code isn't my own, so it's hard to edit it without much trial and error...

Comment: Ah. I found out what I did wrong :D worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Are you for hire? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting location, try window.open()

```
window.open(SearchUrl+SearchQuery);
```

Comment: window.open() = SearchUrl+SearchQuery; you mean? Results in an empty window, nothing else loads. Though I have to say, what a quick response :D

Comment: sorry, was on my iPhone and it's hard to type...  You pass the url to window.open(), I edited the answer