# Bind function to submit event

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I´m trying to bind a simple function to a submit event, that:

1. Retrieves the values of all input fields
2. Sets the action attribute of the form
3. Submits the form

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049614/jquery-target-blank-atr-where-to-include-this-in-the-script/5049634#5049634) - I came up with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fbook').bind('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var baseURL = $(this).children('#base').val();
        var hotelID = $(this).children('#destination').val();
        var dateIn = $(this).children('#show-date-in').val();
        var location = baseURL + "&hotelID=" + hotelID + "&dateIn=" + dateIn;
        $(this).attr('action', location);
        $(this).submit();
    });
});
```

And here´s the jsFiddle with HTML and JS: http://jsfiddle.net/mattvic/2wRHc/47/

Unfortunately it doesn´t work and I just can´t see where I went wrong. I hope someone can spot the error.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will go into an infinite loop, because `$(this).submit()` calls the submit handler bound to the form element, which triggers the handler that calls `$(this).submit()`, which calls the submit handler bound to the form element, and so on.

If you use the form's own `submit` method, you can avoid the recursion:

```
this.submit();
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes totally sense! Would be a good tutorial example of recursion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the form contains a button of type `submit`, your `$(this).submit()` won't work. Instead, try the following -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#booking-button').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var baseURL = $("#fbook").children('#base').val();
        var hotelID = $("#fbook").children('#destination').val();
        var dateIn = $('#show-date-in').val();
        var location = baseURL + "&hotelID=" + hotelID + "&dateIn=" + dateIn;
        $("#fbook").attr('action', location);
        $("#fbook").submit();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wRHc/55/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fbook').submit(function(event) {
        var baseURL = $('#base', this).val();
        var hotelID = $('#destination', this).val();
        var dateIn = $('#show-date-in', this).val();
        var location = baseURL + "&hotelID=" + hotelID + "&dateIn=" + dateIn;
        $(this).attr('action', location);

    });
});
```